# My Fixed Menu Nav Header won't stay in the div it is contained in. Is it a responsive issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Ok I can't figure this out for the life of me. I have spent a couple days on it.

I have a jquery snippet that takes a nav bar in a relative position and upon hitting the top of the screen switches it to a fixed position.  I have this working fine on another site but on this site when I have varying screen sizes the nav bar slides to the left or right.  Happens with larger or smaller screen sizes then mine.

Here is the site. http://curtisj.trafficflo.net/

How can I get the navigation header to stay put in the container div for the content of the site?

here is a jsfiddle but I don't know how to get fiddle to use my jquery.

[jsfiddle of code](http://jsfiddle.net/nbA9x/)

Here is the code of the jquery... I don't know if jquery is the issue though.

```
// JavaScript Document
/*     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed'),
            elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
            elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
            //alert(elTop); 
            jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
                var height = jQuery(window).height();
                var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                if(scrollTop>=elTop){
                    //add fixed
                    jQuery(el).addClass('scroll_fixed').css("left",elLeft+"px");
                }else{
                    //clear fixed
                    jQuery(el).removeClass('scroll_fixed').attr('style','');
                }
            })
        }
    })
       */
       // JavaScript Document
    /* jQuery(window).load(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed'),
            elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
            elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
            //alert(elTop); 
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft);
        }
    }) */
    var setInter = null;
    var session = null;

    setInter = setInterval(function(){
        if(jQuery('header,div,p,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,a').hasClass('isa-scroll-fixed')){
            var el = jQuery('.isa-scroll-fixed');
            session =  jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll');
            //alert(session);

            if(session == '2'){
                jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','2');
            }else{
                jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','1');
            }
            if(session == '1'){
                setValue(el);
            }
        }
    }, 200);
    function setValue(el){
        var setScroll = jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll');
        elTop = jQuery(el).offset().top;
        elLeft = jQuery(el).offset().left;
        //alert(elTop);
        jQuery(el).attr('set-scroll','2');
        scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft);
    };
    function scrollFixed(el,elTop,elLeft){
        jQuery(document).unbind('scroll').scroll(function(){
            //alert(elTop);
            var height = jQuery(window).height();
            var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop>=elTop){
                //add fixed
                jQuery(el).addClass('scroll_fixed').css("left",elLeft+"px");
            }else{
                //clear fixed
                jQuery(el).removeClass('scroll_fixed').attr('style','');
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: `88
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getScroll'  scrolling-header.js:5` fix this error first.

Comment: that is a conflict that has nothing to do with the situation.

Comment: Why come here, ask for free advice, and reject a helpful tip?

Comment: because the helpful tip, while obvious, has nothing to do with what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap everything in a `container`.

### Also, use `absolute positioning` on your `div` **outside** `contentSection_interactive`

I wish I could reproduce, but you have a lot of plugins going on and you haven't produced `code` or a `fiddle`.

## Here to help once you do that.

**Common Full Scale `DIV`s**

- width:100%;
- hright:100%;
- position:absolute;

Comment: Before you ask, why are you including your `absolute` bar within your `div`? Just add it at the `body`, as in outside or above the `document` info. It's `absolute`. Use it as such,

Comment: what div are you assigning that too?  I am not seeing that helping in dev tools?

Comment: I think it's bootstrap attached to my template... I think it is a media queries running a muck.

Answer (score 0):

header.navbar is fixed value.

You have to use @media to change its value for different screen sizes.

Comment: check the header.nav class I tested my side(might be I missed some thing), but its taking 1 single property of 962px which is fixed,even in smaller screen.